# Delete by Query with Sort in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to delete the most current item in my Elasticsearch index sorted by `myDateField` which is a date type. Is that possible? I want something like this query but this would delete all matching items even though I have the size at 1.

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {

        }
    },
    "size" : "1",
    "sort" : [
        {
            "myDateField" : {
                "order" : "desc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete by query is unlikely to support any `sorting` features.

If you try Delete by query - however you'll get the error: request does not support [sort]. I couldn't find any documentation saying that the "sort" parameter is not supported in delete by query.

I've one idea to do it but don't know it's the best way or not?

**Step 1:** Do a normal query based on your conditions+sorting and get those ids.

**Step 2:** Build a bulk query to delete all documents retrieved above by id those you got on Step 1.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I was hoping to do this in one step but that makes sense to have to do it in two steps. Would I also add `?refresh=wait_for` to wait in step 2 for the document to be deleted before attempting another query?

Comment: Yeah, if refresh=wait_for, then wait for a refresh to make this operation visible to search